# ptest on groupby() python

Tags: python, group-by, hypothesis-test

I've a dataframe as below:

```
Region   Votes

    A          23
    B          26
    A          32
    B          46
    A          32
    B          24
```

I calculated mean of votes for region A and B by following code `data.groupby('Region')['Votes'].mean()`.Now I've to do ptest to determine whether this difference is statistically significant.I tried this code

```
one = data[data['Region']=='one']
two = data[data['Region']=='two']

print(st.ttest_ind(one['Votes'], two['Votes'])).
```

I'm getting nan in output instead of values i.e

```
  Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change:

```
one = data[data['Region']=='one']
two = data[data['Region']=='two']
```

to

```
one = data[data['Region']=='A']
two = data[data['Region']=='B']
```

It will work. Or, do it all at once using:

```
st.ttest_ind(data.loc[data.Region == 'A', 'Votes'], data.loc[data.Region == 'B', 'Votes'])
#Ttest_indResult(statistic=-0.3927922024247863, pvalue=0.7145066681331176)
```

Or use a groupby, converting the `Votes` from each region to a list first:

```
gb = df.groupby('Region')['Votes'].apply(list)
st.ttest_ind(*gb)
#Ttest_indResult(statistic=-0.3927922024247863, pvalue=0.7145066681331176)
```